# Why Windows Forms app doesn't save the file to folder

Tags: vb.net, excel, office-interop

I have a Windows Forms application. In this application I save a Excel file to folder. This is the function that save the file:

```
Public Sub ExportToXls(ByRef dt As DataTable, ByRef path As String)
    On Error Resume Next

    'I use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel version = 12
    Dim xlApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
    Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value

    xlApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets(1) 
    For i1 As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
      xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, i1 + 1) = dt.Columns(i1).Caption
    Next
    For i1 As Integer = 0 To dt.FieldCount - 1
      xlWorkSheet.Cells(2, i1 + 1) = dt.Fields(i1)
    Next

    Dim fi As New FileInfo(path)
    If fi.Exists Then
      fi.Delete()
    End If
    ' Default path is X:\WMisch.xls
    ' here on X: I have all rights.
    xlWorkSheet.SaveAs(Filename:=path, FileFormat:=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlExcel8) 

    xlWorkBook.Close()
    xlApp.Quit()

    xlApp = Nothing
    xlWorkBook = Nothing
    xlWorkSheet = Nothing

    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

All works fine on more that 1 PC/servers but on one Server, with Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard, DOESN'T WORK (doesn't save the file to path X:\WMisch.xls). Here, on this server is installed Office 2003 but I installed also MS Office Interop version 12.

Can anybody say me where is the problem? 
Thanks!

Comment: Please define "Doesn't work" - is there an exception? Which one? Which line throws the error? Is the output different than expected? In what way is it different?

Comment: I don't have a error but the app doesn't save the file to X:\WMisch.xls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you're using `On Error Resume Next`. Rather use a `Try..Catch` statement. [**This**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk6t46tz.aspx) might help you find you error.

Comment: Not only that, NEVER use `On Error Resume Next` again.  You're telling the application that, if anything goes wrong, regardless of what it is, just carry on and don't bother telling anyone.  Is that really a good strategy?

Comment: This is good for client. So application never close himself after one "Fatal Error"...

Comment: You can do the same with the 'Try...Catch' method that I mentioned.